# Insert an hidden character in an HTML text string?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

[Insert an hidden character in text string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887301/insert-an-hidden-character-in-text-string-using-javascript)
 - This question was answered by suggesting the OP try alternative actions to accomplish his/her goal. The question is unanswered in my opinion. So how is it done? How do you insert a hidden character into a string.
Hidden character must serve as a delimiter in a list where list items can contain common delimiters like commas and and such. 
Use of tagged technologies only...

Comment: You mean you need to insert a space in your string?

Comment: What do you mean by, "Use of tagged technologies only..."?

Comment: The reason they didn't answer the question you linked is because the OP presented an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/168341) where there's a better solution than that proposed by the OP. Perhaps that's the case here as well.

Comment: Well you can use custom tags like `lol<hiddencharacter> lol`. The browser will parse it and show nothing `lol lol` but you can still use it for other *vague* purposes. Note that with this you're violating all standard specifications which means your document is not (x)html(5) valid...

Comment: I'm sorry if I was vague. I need to store a list of values in a DB, but I do not want to separate values by a comma, since a comma is present in some values, e.g. San Francisco, CA. So I thought that a hidden character would be less ambiguous.

Comment: @Herbert Tagged as in tagged in post: PHP javascript html and mysql. Use of these technologies to accomplish the goal.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui I need to separate values with a character that isn't present in any of the values.

Comment: @Herbert I'm open to suggestions concerning your "better solution"

Comment: @HamZa Hmmm. You got a point, as well as a solution. #indecisive

Answer (score 0):

This question:
[Unicode to a Form with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165501/unicode-to-a-form-with-javascript)
shows how to add Unicode characters to a text field via JavaScript. It satisfies me sufficiently for me to consider it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can use the unicode control character

```
<span id="taggable">lo&#8232;l</span>
```

gives

> lol

And if you want to add it you can do something like:

```
 var span= document.getElementById('tagabble');
 span.innerHTML +='&#8232;';
```

Comment: Control character!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters

Comment: How would u add this character to a text field. When I add it to a text field it shows the character code in the field, visible to all.

Comment: This shows up as L SEP and is visible on Microsoft Edge